# Can i override the behavior of .jsp implicit objects?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, glassfish-4

I want to know if I can make the .jsp file to use another class that inherits the behavior of HttpServlet when it makes the translation from .jsp to .java . In other words, I want to override the behavior of the HttpServlet used in .jsp.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page extends="your.servlet.pkg.servletclass">
```

Note it doesn't have to be a servlet, but otherwise that will most probably break your jsp.